# Getting Misaligned access runtime error in c++ for a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, memory, vector

```
Trie()
{
    nxt.assign(26, NULL);
    cout << nxt.size() << endl;
    Trie* root = this;
    isWord = false;
}

/** Inserts a word into the trie. */
void insert(string word)
{
    auto node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "node: " << node<< ":" << "word[i] -'a': " << word[i] - 'a' << endl;
        if (node->nxt[word[i] - 'a'] == NULL ) // misaligned memory access here
        node->nxt[word[i]-'a'] = new Trie(); 
        node = node->nxt[word[i]-'a'];
    }
    node->isWord = true;
}
```

I am getting the following error although the vector seems to have correct length: Member access within misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebe for type 'Trie' which requires 8 byte alignment. Why is the nxt vector elements not accessible?

Update:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Trie {
public:
  Trie() {

    nxt.assign(26, NULL);
    isWord = false;
  }

  void insert(string word) {
    auto node = this;

    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
      if (!node->nxt[word[i]-'a']) {
    cout << " nxt entry not found... :" << word[i] << endl;
    node->nxt[word[i]-'a'] = new Trie();
      }
      else {
    cout << "nxt entry found! :" << word[i]  << endl;
    node = node->nxt[word[i]-'a'];
      }
      node->isWord = true;
    }

  }
  bool search(string word) {
    auto node = this;
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
      if (!node->nxt[word[i]-'a']) return false;
      node = node->nxt[word[i]-'a'];

    }
    return node->isWord ? true: false;

  }

private:
  vector<Trie*> nxt;
  bool isWord;



};

int main() {

  Trie* trie = new Trie();

  trie->insert("test");

  cout << "found test: " << trie->search("test") << endl;
  cout << "success!" << endl;



  return 0;
}
```

This runs! Bailey's comment helped me realize my mistake. I had declared a local root in ctor. The intent was to only initialize the class member, root! Thank you!

Comment: So root is defined inn the constructor but not in insert. How can you use it in the insert function? It's impossible. Unless you have a root defined in a bigger scope but we cant tell!

Comment: In the `Trie` constructor, `Trie* root = this;` is assigning a **local variable** that *shadows* the `root` member that `insert()` is trying to access. This means the `root` member is *uninitialized* when `insert()` needs it.  Since `root` just points to `this`, what is the point of having `root` at all? Just use `this` instead

Comment: Yes! silly me! root was actually a class member- I effectively created a local variable of the same name in the ctor and got myself confused! Thank you!